# locationUpdated callback not being hit on ios device but it is on Android and Javascript

Tags: codenameone

My question is about the LocationRequest.setLocationListener method in the Codenameone API.  I'm trying to set up a map screen that will allow a user to click a button to enable GPS monitoring (and will eventually write that GPS data to a database, but that's irrelevant for now).  I found some basic boilerplate code here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/mapping-natively.html

I then modified it slightly to let the phone vibrate each time a location update was made (so that I could walk around the block and get instant feedback that it was working as intended).  I did just that and I found that the Android device was working perfectly, however my iPhone was not.  It would get the location once and then never again.  Here's my code:

```js
Form hi = new Form("Native Maps Test");
hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
cnt = new MapContainer();
hi.addCommand(new Command("Track") {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
  final InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
  dlg = ip.showInifiniteBlocking();
  LocationManager l = LocationManager.getLocationManager();
  LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCUARCY, 2000);     l.setLocationListener(new LocationListener() { public void locationUpdated(Location
  location) {
  if (Display.getInstance().getCurrent() == dlg) {
    dlg.dispose();
  }
  Display.getInstance().vibrate(1);
}
public void providerStateChanged(int newState) {
  if (Display.getInstance().getCurrent() == dlg) {
    dlg.dispose();
  }
}
}, locationRequest);
}
});
```

Note that the "dlg" stuff is probably irrelevant, I just snagged it from the URL mentioned above.

Hope someone with experience in this area can help me out!

Cheers,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set `ios.locationUsageDescription` to a valid value, without that [build hint](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) location won't work on iOS.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the reply.  The ios.locationUsageDescription build hint is indeed set.  I believe when I imported the maps API using your CN1 wizard, it added all of the relevant build hints.  Here's an image of my build hints as they exist right now: http://www.sophonaloaf.com/ios_issue.png

Comment: I've noticed you use vibrate(1) which might not be noticeable on iOS. Did you try some other forms of notification?

Comment: Hi Shai, with vibrate(1), I get a single vibration on iOS, so I believe it is actually working.  Just to be sure though, I've tried a few different things such as using a larger vibrate setting and having the map zoom in on each locationUpdated callback.  In all instances, it works the first time but then never again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel like I've tried everything but just can't get this working on iOS.  I've started looking into ways to create my own background location manager to 'force' location requests every so often.  I see that CN1 has a background fetch feature.  I played around with this briefly and it seems to work nicely for what I need it to do.  My thought is that on the press of a button, I'll enable a foreground thread that loops every x seconds and retrieves the location (and then draws lines to the map/updates a database).  If the app is paused/minimized, the thread will stop and the background fetch will take over the responsibility of retrieving location updates and writing to the DB.  When the app is resumed, the background fetcher will stop and the foreground thread will start again.  Does anyone with experience in these concepts see anything glaringly wrong with this idea?  My hope is that the background fetch will serve two purposes - enable me to work around the issue I'm seeing with the locationUpdated callback on iOS and ensure that GPS tracking happens regardless of if the OS garbage collects the app in the background.  I'm aware that this might be a strain on the battery, but I'm ok with this seeing as how the app is being built for the purposes of tracking lost pets, in which case I feel it's a technical issue that users will more easily accept.